# Dinamically update meta tags for social share in angular4

Tags: angular, share

I'm running into a problem and I want to know which approachs are more recommended to fix it. I'm using MetaService within angular 4 for update dinamically the 'meta' tags in components that will be shared in social media, however, facebook sharer, for example, doesnt recognize the updated values and loads the default values of my tags in dialog share. So, I ask, which ways fix this?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. You can read more about [how to ask a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Answer (score 2):

Angular is SPA (Single Page Application) meaning the client will only fetch content from the server once and then handle routing to different pages in the client.

Under the hood the webserver is configured to route all traffic to one html file which is /index.html containing the code for the application. What you need is a way to serve different meta tags based on the initial request url. The two options I know of are:

**Using server side rendering**

Using server side rendering, Angular will produce static pages for each route which enables you to set specific meta tags for each route as well.

See [this tutorial](https://medium.com/burak-tasci/angular-4-with-server-side-rendering-aka-angular-universal-f6c228ded8b0) on converting your application to use server side rendering

**Using Node.js, Express & ejs to inject meta data into index.html**

Using the [ejs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) with Express you can dynamically inject meta tags into your index.html

Using ejs you will rename your index.html to index.ejs and configure it to contain variables

```
<title>
<%=title%>
</title>
<meta itemprop="description" content="<%=description%>">
```

Configure Express to use ejs to deliver different meta data based on requested url

```
router.get('/pageOne', function(req, res, next) {

var metaData = {
       title: 'Page One',
       descriptio: 'This is page one'
   };

res.render('index.ejs', metaData );
});

router.get('/pageTwo', function(req, res, next) {

var metaData = {
       title: 'Page two',
       descriptio: 'This is page two'
   };

res.render('index.ejs', metaData );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook and Twitter crawlers (unlike Google) do not execute any JavaScript, so you have to do this via server-side rendering. I did it by switching to Angular Universal and then using MetaService.

Note that porting to Angular Universal can be a major change, so do your research before deciding if you want to make the leap.